# value keys is not a member of play.api.libs.json.JsValue

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm try to get the head from the keys of JsValue type in Scala. I googled a lot to know how to get the head key from JsValue type.

Finally, I found that **result.keys.head** is the way to get the head key, but it throws **error** ***value keys is not a member of play.api.libs.json.JsValue***.

And my **result variable** has the below form of data:

```
{
    "intents": [{
        "intent": "feeling",
        "confidence": 0.1018563217175903
    }],
    "entities": [],
    "input": {
        "text": "{reset-encounter}"
    },
    "output": "Good"
}
```

**Code:**

```
import play.api.libs.json._
val jsonStr = """
{
        "intents": [{
            "intent": "feeling",
            "confidence": 0.1018563217175903
        }],
        "entities": [],
        "input": {
            "text": "{reset-encounter}"
        },
        "output": "Good"
    }
"""
val result = Json.parse(jsonStr)
println("key: ", result.keys.head)
```

At **result.keys.head** line, throws error.

I'm not sure but I think, may be I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: Please post the actual code that is producing the error

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco: Thanks. Please view the code.

Comment: `JsValue` actually does not have `keys`. `JsObject` does. You need to convert it to `JsObject`. - `result.asInstanceOf[JsObject].keys.head`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Json.parse` produces a `JsValue`, which could represent any type of json object (boolean, number, array, etc). If you know you're working with an object, you can use `.as[JsObject]`:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val result = Json.parse(jsonStr).as[JsObject]
println("key: " + result.keys.head)
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to get? That's not the way to deal with `play.api.Json` objects.

.keys would result in a `Map`, not in a JsValue.

Check the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson

If you want to access a specific key (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#Traversing-a-JsValue-structure) you should try:

```
result \ "keyName"
```

or for a recursive search:

```
result \\ "keyName"
```

Comment: if you want to model json objects to your domain (case classes) check http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json/ and http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json-part2/

Comment: As @Sarvesh Kumar Singh mention, Json Object has **keys** while JsValue hasn't. Assume, I don't know about the keys of Json Object, then I need **.keys** to get them.